# JavaScript Highest Representable Number

Tags: javascript, node.js

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin) asks about the highest number in JavaScript without losing precision. Here, I ask about the highest representable number in JavaScript. Some answers to the other question reference the answer to this question, but they do not answer that question, so I hope I am safe asking here.

I tried to find the answer, but I got lost halfway through. The highest number representable in JavaScript seems to be somewhere between 2^1023 and 2^1024. I went further (in the iojs REPL) with

```
var highest = Math.pow(2, 1023);
for(let i = 1022; i > someNumber; i--) {
  highest += Math.pow(2, someNumber);
}
```

The highest number here seems to be when `someNumber` is between 969 and 970. This means it is between (2^1023 + 2^1022 + ... + 2^970) and (2^1023 + 2^1022 + ... + 2^969). I'm not sure how to go further without running out of memory and/or waiting years for a loop or function to finish.

What is the highest number representable in JavaScript? Does JavaScript store all digits of this number, or just some, because whenever I see numbers of 10^21 or higher they are represented in scientific notation? Why can JavaScript represent these extremely high numbers, especially if it can "remember" all the digits? Isn't JavaScript a base 64 language?

Finally, why is this the highest representable number? I am asking because it is not an integer exponent of 2. Is it because it is a floating point number? If we took the highest floating point number, would that be related to some exponent of 2?

Comment: I apologize if this is a duplicate of another question. I (surprisingly) couldn't find the answer by searching.

Comment: Yes. for future responses it is [here][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin

Comment: I mentioned that question in my question, but I'm asking the highest number that JavaScript can handle, while that question is asking about the highest number it can handle *without losing precision*. Please read the question before you comment.

Comment: I wish the "duplicate answer" flag had a "No my question is different,*I already explained how*" resolution. Because I did already explain how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECMAScript uses [IEEE 754 floating points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) to represent all numbers (integers and floating points) in memory. It uses [double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) (64 bit), so the largest possible number would be the following (in binary):

```
(-1)^0 * (1.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111)_2 * 2^1023
     ^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^
 sign bit                     52 binary digits                         exponent
```

That is `1.9999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375 * 2^1023`, which is exactly equal to `179769313486231570814527423734518473246981451219193357160576872808257310254570927992989173324623785766498017753719800531497718555288192667185248845624861831489179706103179456665410545164365169396987674822445002542175370097858557402467390846365155202987281348776667818932226328810501776426180817703854493120592.218308495538871112145305600`. That number is also available in JavaScript as `Number.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: The question I linked to actually referenced Number.MAX_VALUE (though it's not an answer to that question) but I kind of wanted to know why, and also the exact number. By the way, you say that number is equal to 1.797693134862315708145274237e+308, but is that *exactly* equal, or approximately?

Comment: @trysis Amended my answer to include the numbers with exact precision.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript uses IEE 754 double-precision floating point numbers, aka the [binary64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). This format has 1 sign bit, 11 bits of exponent, and 52 bits of mantissa.

The highest possible number is that which is encoded using the highest possible exponents and mantissa, with a 0 sign bit. Except that the exponent value of `7ff` (base 16) is used to encode `Infinity` and `NaN`s. The largest number is therefore encoded as `7fef ffff ffff ffff`, and its value is (1 + (1 − 2^(−52))) × 2^1023.

Refer to the linked article for further details about the formula.